# Using namespaces with autoloading

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

So i have got this small piece of code that auto loads the classes. Everything is going allright until i add namespaces. I get the error that it can't find the Class. But when i remove the namespace it works again. (It also works when i include the wbp.Foo.php directly.)

autoloader.php

```
<?php

function autoloadLib($className){
    $filename = "lib/wbp." . $className . ".php";
    if(is_readable($filename)){
        require $filename;
    }
}

spl_autoload_register("autoloadLib");
```

index.php

```
<?php

include "autoloader.php";
use Foobar\Foo;
echo Foo::Bar();
```

lib/wbp.Foo.php

```
<?php

namespace Foobar;

class Foo {
    public static function Bar(){
        return "foobar";
    }
}
```

Comment: Because i am implementing this in a project where every core php code starts with the prefix wbp.

Comment: Deleted comments.. nice.

Comment: Try to `var_dump($className)` inside the autoload function. Maybe the namespace is part of the className passed in and so `wpb.Foobar\Foo.php` is not readable?

Comment: I get string(10) "Foobar\Foo". So yeh its kinda logical it can't find wbp.Foobar\Foo.php. But what approach should i do?

Comment: You could either parse the name to a path and move the class file to a folder structure that has the namespace as part of it's location (suggested) or remove the namespace in the autoload and just load using the classname. I suggest the former simply because the point of namespaces is to allow two classes with the same name to exist with different definitions. If you just use the classname, you can't really support two files in the same location. Renaming and using a new path could be as simple as `str_replace('\\', '.', $className)`.

Comment: I think i will do your suggested one. I really need the namespaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the autoload, the `$className` variable includes the namespace. You need to either move the class into a file/folder structure that includes the namespace or remove the namespace from the classname and just load based on the class. I suggest the former simply because the whole point of namespaces is to allow two different class definitions with the same name. You can't really have two files in the same space on disk with the same name. Renaming the `$className` could be as simple as `str_replace('\\', '.', $className)` and renaming your class to `wbp.NameSpace.ClassName.php`.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with namespaces, you should simple read PSR-4 documentation at http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/  - there is also example of autoloader.

PSR-4 is becoming a standard so the best way is to do this in that way

Comment: This might actually come in handy, thanks. Only i have to change things in the project now..